# Cannot locate default realm from javaKerberos Sql Server connection on docker Linux

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, jdbc, kerberos

I'm trying to connect to a sql server instance via javaKerberos.   I can get this  to work on Windows (non-docker)  and a nondocker Linux instance, but I keep getting a "Cannot locate default realm" error on Linux docker.  Note, I'm running an Amazon Linux docker image because ultimately I'm trying to get this to work on ECS, though at the moment im testing this on my Docker Desktop for Windows.

Do any of you have any suggestion on what to try?  I've tried MANY combnations of the krb5.conf and various java command line flags, but nothing has worked yet.

Below is all the pertinent kerberos config items I've been using.

**Command to run jar on docker instance**

```
java -jar app.jar  -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/opt/krb5.conf  -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/jaas.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5NameElement.getInstance(Krb5NameElement.java:129) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:95) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getNameElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.getElement(GSSNameImpl.java:477) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.init(GSSNameImpl.java:201) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:128) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:58) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar!/:na]
```

**krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = US.TEST.COM
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = true
ticket_lifetime = 86400
renew_lifetime = 604800
forwardable = true
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac
udp_preference_limit = 1

[realms]
US.TEST.COM = {
kdc = crldap1.us.test.com
admin_server =crldap1.us.test.com
}

[domain_realm]
 .us.test.com = US.TEST.COM
 us.test.com = US.TEST.COM

 

[default_realm]
 .us.test.com = US.TEST.COM
 us.test.com = US.TEST.COM
```

**jaas.conf**

```
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=false
  useTicketCache=true
  doNotPrompt=true;
};
```

**Connection String**

```
spring.datasource.url =jdbc:sqlserver://DBSERVER\\SERVER_DEV;databaseName=DB1;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;integratedSecurity=true;userName=user@US.TEST.COM;password=P@SSW0RD
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could always check is the encoding of the krb5.conf file.

We've had trouble with the encoding being automatically set to `UTF-8-BOM`.
Apparently some systems can't handle that and thus can't read the krb5.conf. This will trigger the `KrbException: Cannot locate default realm`.

Changing the encoding to `UTF-8` did the trick for me.

Should this not work I would suggest checking if the krb5.conf file cannot be read for some other reason. In my experience this error is usually caused by problems in reading the file.